# uniqueness of joint probability mass function given the marginals and the covariance

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, covariance

Let X and Y be two nonnegative, integer-valued random variables. Is there a way to find the joint probability mass function, i.e.

$$ 
\mathbb{P}(X= k, Y= h) 
$$

for some $k,h\geq 0$, given the marginals and the covariance?

Moreover, it is true that $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}h\,k\,\mathbb{P}(X= k, Y= h)$.

I know that I can write

$$
\mathbb{E}[XY]=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}h\,k\,g_{h,k}
$$

Can I conclude that $\mathbb{P}(X= k, Y= h)=g_{h,k}$? Is there uniqueness?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean from $g_{h,k}$?

Comment: A function depending on h and k, whose expression I know

Answer (score 0):

In general $E[X]=\sum_x xp(x)$; So, obviously, for $Z=XY$ we would have
\begin{align*}
E[Z]=&\sum_z zP(Z)\\
=&\sum_x \sum_y xy P(X,Y)\\
=&~a
\end{align*}
where $a$ is a constant. But your question is how many coefficient sets $\{c_{x,y}\}$ we can find so that
\begin{align*}
\sum_x \sum_y x~y~c_{x,y}=a
\end{align*}
For sure it is not unique. For example for an arbitrary pair ($x_1$ and $y_1$) if you change $c_{x_1,y_1}$ to $c_{x_1,y_1}+1$ then the total result would be increased by $x_1 y_1$. Now, for another arbitrary pair ($x_2$ and $y_2$), you can compensate this difference by decreasing $c_{x_2,y_2}$ value to become $(c_{x_2,y_2}-\frac{x_1 y_1}{x_2 y_2})$.

As you see there exist infinite sets of $\{c_{x,y}\}$ which all of them result in $a$.

Comment: Ok, but $P(X,Y)$ is not known in advance. I only have a double series representation for $\mathbb{E}[XY]$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\sum_{x}\sum_{x}xyg(x,y)$. Can infer that $g(x,y)$ is the joint probability mass function I am looking for? By the way, thanks for your answer.

Comment: From where do you have this formula? The standard formula for $E[XY]$ is what I wrote. For finite-domain Random Variables you may also be able to find another $g(x,y)$ which satisfies the formula but what's the benefit?
You want to solve it as an exercise?

Comment: Also, your question had two parts and my answer was not complete. I was busy and I got disconnected; I edited it just now.

Comment: Well... I know the expression for $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)(X-Y-1)]$, let's say f(x,y). I also know $\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$, $\mathbb{E}[X]$, $\mathbb{E}[Y^{2}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ because I know the marginals. Therefore I can compute the expression for $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ and I know I can write it as a double (power) series. My question is: are the coefficients of this representation the joint probability distribution I want? Is this uniquely determined?

Comment: @Alex I hope that you have gotten your answer, by this edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a system of linear equations and inequalities that characterizes the set of all feasible solutions. Given $P(X=k),$ $k\ge 0$, $P(Y=h),$ $h\ge 0$ and $E[XY]$ this system will be 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\sum\limits_{h\ge0}g_{h,k}&=&P(X=k),\ k\ge 0,\\
\sum\limits_{k\ge0}g_{h.k}&=&P(Y=h),\ h\ge 0,\\
\sum\limits_{k,h\ge 0}khg_{h,k}&=&E[XY],\\
\sum\limits_{k,h\ge 0}g_{h,k}&=&1,\\
g_{kh}&\ge& 0,\ k,h\ge 0.
\end{array}
$$
The solution is not unique whenever the support set of at least one of the variables has three or more values and the other variable is not constant (support has at least two values). This is because you have $|supp X|+|supp Y|$ independent equations but $|supp X|\times |supp Y|$ unknowns.